# Send IOS Notification on Firestore Database change using Node.JS

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have built an IOS App using Swift which has a WhatsApp style messaging feature using Firebase Firestore Database & am trying to set up the notifications that the message receiver gets when a new message is saved to the database.

I successfully installed Firebase messaging and am receiving the Device Token through the App Delegate. I can then use that token to send a test message from the Firebase Messaging Console to the chosen device without a problem.

So, I moved onto setting up Node.JS (*please be gentle, I am knew at this bit*) and figured I would get the test setup like it says in the Firebase Docs, initially just listening for a new document in my database & then performing a simple task - in this case it was just changing a name field to capitals. The code for that working is:

```
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");

initializeApp();


exports.makeuppercase = onDocumentCreated("/tester/{documentId}", (event) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
  const name = event.data.data().name;

  // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `event.params`
  logger.log("Uppercasing", event.params.documentId, name);

  const uppercase = name.toUpperCase();

  // You must return a Promise when performing
  // asynchronous tasks inside a function
  // such as writing to Firestore.
  // Setting an 'uppercase' field in Firestore document returns a Promise.
  return event.data.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});
```

My final test task to put it all together (& then write the real code) is to now get a test message to trigger when that name gets changed to Uppercase. I have read/watched so many tutorials but nothing I do seems to work. My most recent code included to the above is:

```
exports.sendListenerPushNotification = onDocumentCreated("/tester/{documentId}", (event) => {
  const name = event.data.data().name;  
  const FCM = require("fcm-node");
  const serverKey = require("MY_SERVER_KEY");
  const fcm = new FCM(serverKey);
  const message = {
    to: "SAME_DEVICE_ID_AS_TEST",
    collapse_key: "apns-collapse-id",
    notification: {
      title: "Title of your push notification",
      body: "Body of your push notification",
    },
  };
  fcm.send(message, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
  });
});
```

The code deploys without errors but no test notification is received. At this point, I've read so many different things that I am confused as anything! I am more than happy to read documentation but, I find this node.js/server stuff very confusing & anything I seem to try doesn't work.

Could any experienced Dev explain in simple terms how to take the next step & send that test notification when the name changes to uppercase?

Really sorry if I am am being stupid & this is easy but, like I say, I am a node.js newbie.

Many thanks in advance.